# Jquery resizable() showing resize icon but not resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I have a page with two resizable `div`s. The first one works properly, the second one shows the resize icon but doesn't get resized.

This is my html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.css">
        <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <img id="img_site_top" src="site_top.png">
            <div id="img_header" style="position: absolute; left: 7px; top: 7px; background-image: url(header.png); width:980px; height:106px;">
                <a id="img_logo" class="jqDrag" style="position:absolute; top: -11px; left: 0px; width:350px; height:107px; background-image: url(logo.png); background-size: 100% 100%;background-repeat: no-repeat; border: 1px solid white">
                </a>
            </div>
            <img id="img_site" src="site.png">
            <img id="img_welcome_panel" src="welcome_panel.png">
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(
            function(){
                $('#img_logo').draggable().resizable({ aspectRatio: true }); //works
                $('#img_header').resizable(); //doesn't work: shows the icon, but doesn't resize.
            }
        );
    </script>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]

Where:

- The first resize is applied to the light brown box (`$('#img_logo')`)
- The second resize is applied to the light blue box (`$('#img_header')`), although it may seem it's applied to the gray box.

[Demo here](http://backslash.site88.net/)

What am I missing? Why the first box just works and the second doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the order of initialisation.  Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/77/ .
Replace this :

```
 $(function(){
            $('#img_logo').draggable().resizable({ aspectRatio: true }); //works
            $('#img_header').resizable(); //doesn't work: shows the icon, but doesn't resize.
  });
```

With:

```
 $(function(){                
            $('#img_header').resizable();
            $('#img_logo').draggable().resizable({ aspectRatio: true });

   });
```

Comment: Hey! That works! Can you explain why does order matter?

Comment: I have no idea about this. I think it's jQuery bug . You can find more here : http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5025 . I think order is important only if we have nested resizable elements otherwise order does not matter. Anyway if that works for you, you can mark it as answer.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep that in mind for future uses of the resizable function :)

Answer (score 0):

it may be because of absolute positioning just change it to just set the

`position: relative;`

Comment: It can't be the problem. `$('#img_logo')` is absolutely positioned too, and the resizing works without issues. Anyway, just tried it, that's not the problem.